# Export HTML data table to Excel using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can you please let me know, how we can proceed in this case we have a pure HTML data in the form of Tables which should be converted to proper excel sheet.

This is the source code which I have written, I get an exception --> 
Error: Invalid header signature; read 0x6D78206C6D74683C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0|#]

```
    // Resulting byte stream from the DB
    resultBytes = dokumentSession.getXlsZuAuftrag(ts);
    if (resultBytes != null && resultBytes.length > 0) {
        try {
            InputStream fos = new ByteArrayInputStream(resultBytes);
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fos);
            workbook.createSheet("sheet1");
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ipa_loader.xls");
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {// Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Please let me know any inputs on this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that parses HTML and creates cells in your XLS.  Your question does not make sense in the context of the code you have provided.

Comment: @JimGarrison Can you please give me any hints?.. I have never used apache-POI API before, this was something I picked up from examples from apache site.

Comment: That is beyond what can be done here.  Your code seems to think it's reading binary Excel data from `dokumentSession`, opening it as a workbook then writing it out.  The "signature" it's complaining about (`0x6D78206C6D74683C`) decodes as `mx lmth<`.  It would help if you edited your post to include the full stack trace and indicate which line in your code is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 3):

Using any HTML parser you have to parse your HTML content then write the content into Excel using POI.

**Links :**

POI Example

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

HTML Parser Example

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

Also you have easily convert your html code into XLS.
Here you can find the example 
http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/WDJava/Export+to+Excel+%28Without+third+party+APIs%29

Comment: Your links do not help resolve the question. Please provide links that demonstrate specifically and concisely parsing an HMTL table and then writing it out using POI.

Comment: This project seems to implement those steps (read HTML with JSoup, write XLSX with POI): https://github.com/alanhay/html-exporter